# Google Maps, how to capture right click event on POI

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using [gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/).
I need to capture right click event on any point of my map.

```
GMaps.on('rightclick', map.map, function(event) {
  console.log('Right click was captured.')
});
```

The method above works fine if I click on a random point on the map. However if I click on Point Of Interest (POI - bus stop, metro station, famous building, etc.) my callback is not working.

How can I add listener to right clicks on POI?

Comment: Do you need the POI's infowindow?

Comment: Yes, I need POI's info window on left click. Also need my custom action on right click.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need (or want) the POI's infowindow to open when it is clicked, set the `clickableIcons` property in the [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions) to false.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4za7nn2h/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333,
    clickableIcons: false
  });
  GMaps.on('rightclick', map.map, function(event) {
    console.log('Right click was captured.')
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but POI's should remain clickable. I just need my custom action on right click.